# Can't use static library without adding header files in iOS

Tags: xcode

I followed this below link in order to use static library alone by adding just .a file and not including header files.

http://muthukumarela.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/ios-static-libraries-without-adding-header-files/#comments

But still it gives me an error

Please guide someone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Kajal What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I m using the same link it is fine for me.

Comment: Yes, I solved my problem by changing the path type from recursive to non-recursive